# Eclipse JSP project error: org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log SEVERE: action: null

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat

I need to run an instance of an existing JSP web service on my personal PC, The project is currently running on a server with tomcat 6 and java 6. I however get the following error trying to run it on eclipse kepler (Kepler because its compatible with java 6) and tomcat 6 on my setup. The error is:

```
 26 Jan 2020 2:13:25 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
 SEVERE: action: null
 java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Properties.java:418)
        at java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:337)
        at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:325)
        at com.samaxes.webreport.birt.BirtEngine.loadEngineProps(BirtEngine.java:148)
        at com.samaxes.webreport.birt.BirtEngine.initBirtConfig(BirtEngine.java:52)
        at com.samaxes.webreport.plugin.BirtInitializationPlugin.init(BirtInitializationPlugin.java:33)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.initModulePlugIns(ActionServlet.java:869)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.init(ActionServlet.java:336)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1173)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:993)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4420)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4733)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
26 Jan 2020 2:13:25 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Marking servlet action as unavailable
26 Jan 2020 2:13:25 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet  threw load() exception
javax.servlet.UnavailableException
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.initModulePlugIns(ActionServlet.java:880)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.init(ActionServlet.java:336)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1173)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:993)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4420)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4733)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your issue:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Properties.java:418)
        at java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:337)
        at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:325)
        at com.samaxes.webreport.birt.BirtEngine.loadEngineProps(BirtEngine.java:148)
```

Expection raises because of missing .properties file with Birt configuration. To start: https://www.eclipse.org/birt/getting-started/

Comment: Ok, I have now tried everything with birt installs, yet this problem persists. Can you maybe be more clear on the solution? I don't understand if I need to install birt on eclipse (which ive done) or in the tomcat server itself.

Comment: Just some background. I have been employed to do development on this server. The working source code was provided to me. The previous dev was able to run this service on his pc, so there must be some sort of configuration I'm missing. Im thinking birt should've been included and working in the source code I received...

Comment: Well, you already have Birt library in Tomcat server or packed inside your application, because 'BirtEngine' class is present. Problem in configuration file - it does not exist.

Comment: Thanks for the help, seems like I was provided with an incomplete copy of the source code. When I received the source code in full the problem was resolved. Sorry for the inconvenience!